# Quaternion rotation in 3d not working as expected

Tags: c, rotation, quaternions

I am trying to understand how quaternions work and what the proper approach would be to implement arbitrary rotations in three dimensions.

I am using Vulkan and glm for rendering and 3d math resp.

I do have a basic understanding of rotation in three dimensions, that is, you need an axis to rotate around and an angle, hence quaternions are easily constructed from a 3d vector and a float. I also understand that a quaternion is a four dimensional number, i.e., if (x, y, z, w) is a quaternion, it is not as simple as x, y and z being the axis and w being the angle.

The thing that puzzles me most is how I should express rotation of my objects, is it best to chain quaternions, adding a new quaternion each time the object receives some kind of rotate command, or should I just need one quaternion at all time. The reason I am asking is because I would like the object to rotate about the y axis when the mouses moves, but I also want it to rotate about some arbitrary axis, let's call it r, which is perpendicular to the y axis, but also rotates about the y axis when the object itself rotates. The point is, there are two main rotations, y and r.

Objects have several operations, but for setting rotation there is

```
void rn_object_set_rotation(void* o, float x, float y, float z, float degrees) {

    Object object = (Object) o;

    versor q;

    glm_quat_identity(object->node->rotation);
    glm_quat(q, glm_rad(degrees), x, y, z);
    glm_quat_mul(object->node->rotation, q, object->node->rotation);

}
```

to set the rotation to whatever axis and angle, and also

```
void rn_object_rotate(void* o, float x, float y, float z, float degrees) {

    Object object = (Object) o;

    versor q;

    glm_quat(q, glm_rad(degrees), x, y, z);
    glm_quat_mul(object->node->rotation, q, object->node->rotation);

}
```

to "add" a rotation.

The first method could be used to hard reset a rotation, the second should be used when you want to add or change the rotation but with the old as reference (or starting point).

I am not sure if my goal can be achieved with this setup, I imagine having two quaternions in the object, one for the y axis and one for the r axis, then continuously multiplying them throughout the render loop, would work, but that does not scale well and also seems not very intuitive.

The following images show the rotation I want about the y axis.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The next images shows what I want for the r axis (kind of), as you can see, if I rotate it around the y axis (I am calling the rotate method using [0.0, 1.0, 0.0] as axis), the object actually spins around a tilted axis, in the last images you can see how the objects points up, but I want it to keep pointing down like the first (fourth) image. My guess is that the rotation is actually happening in object space and not in world space?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Finally, the last image shows a rotation about [1.0, 1.0, 0.0] (normalized) with 0 degrees (using set_rotation), which puzzles me a lot, I guess the angle is zero so no rotation is happening, that makes sense.

Comment: I tried using quaternions for this sort of thing once but gave up in favour of 3x3 matrices which are slower but easier to understand. Does the API allow you to use matrices instead?

Comment: Yes, but I do want to use quaternions, because they are more efficient.